# How to use tow UITableViews on an iPad using the same view and delegate?

Tags: xcode, ipad, uitableview, delegates

If I wanna use two UITableView in the same View on the iPad, and I try to set different tag on each one.

Could I share the same delegate? Because I try to judge them by tag number, still no work.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if(tableView.tag==0){
        return [array1 count];}

    else if(tableView.tag==1){
        return [array2 count];}
}
```

or just can use one UITableView on one view?

Comment: Seems that the tags are set correctly. This portion of code have no problem.

Comment: Why not use same table with two different sections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not store & compare pointers of the tables

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if(tableView == myTableView1){
        return [array1 count];}
    else if(tableView == myTableView2){
        return [array2 count];}
}
```

Do the same in the rest of the delegate&datasource methods.

To do this, just add 2 IBOutlets in your class and connect them in InterfaceBuilder to your tables.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView* myTableView1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView* myTableView2;
```

Just remember to release them in `-dealloc:`